# Hello! I am trying to do an alternate left/right design on a project using foreach but it is not working

Tags: php, foreach, advanced-custom-fields

This my code. I have used: echo "<img src="" . (++$count % 2 ? $image : 'right') . "">"; to check if my image would show or it would just right in the src section, as a test but my image shows outside of the src code. I am not sure what to do now.

```
    <main>
        <?php
        global $post;
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'stg_start'
        );
        $latest_posts = get_posts($args);
        $description = the_field('start-description');
        $count = 0;
        ?>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <?php
                    $image = the_field('start-image');
                    foreach ($latest_posts as $post) :
                        echo "<img src=\"" . (++$count % 2 ? $image : 'right') . "\">";
                    endforeach;
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <?php
                    foreach ($latest_posts as $post) :
                        echo "<h1>" . the_field('start-title') . "</h1>";
                        echo "<p>by " . " | " . the_field('start-date') . "</p>";
                    endforeach;
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</div>
```

Comment: My first thought would be to look at the html source.  I suspect `$image` is not what you expect it to be. BTW, I like how you’ve used the alternate syntax to match up your blocks (I personally try to expunge all `print` and `echo` commands from the view, using only the short echo tags).

Comment: Hey Thank you for answering, I managed to get help and figure out the problem. This was the solution, just incase anyone else had a problem:

Comment: I guess i can't put the code on here. I had the syntax all wrong.